# How do I automate sending gmails row by row when the cells in a specific column have either a yes or no entered

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function findTextsendupdate(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var startRow = 3// First row of data to process
var numRows = 50  // Number of rows to process
// if a yes is entered in column M
var sendUpdateRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 14);
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var yes = "yes"
var no = "no"
var send = sendUpdateRange.createTextFinder(yes);
send.matchCase(false); //{Boolean} -> match target text's case or not;
  send.matchEntireCell(true); //{Boolean} -> check the whole Range or within;
  send.ignoreDiacritics(true); //{Boolean} -> ignore diacretic signs during match;
  send.matchFormulaText(true); //{Boolean} -> search in formulas (if any) or values;

var dontSend = sendUpdateRange.createTextFinder(no)
  dontSend.matchCase(false); //{Boolean} -> match target text's case or not;
  dontSend.matchEntireCell(true); //{Boolean} -> check the whole Range or within;
  dontSend.ignoreDiacritics(true); //{Boolean} -> ignore diacretic signs during match;
  dontSend.matchFormulaText(true); //{Boolean} -> search in formulas (if any) or values;

//invoke search;
var res = send.findNext();
var tes = dontSend.findNext();
{ //do something with result;
if (tes) {
  var emailNotSent = "Email Not Sent"
  sheet.getRange(startRow, 14, numRows, 1).setValue(emailNotSent)}
if(res) {
  var sendEmail = sendUpdateRange.getValues();
  var emailSent = "Email Sent";
  for (var i = 0; i < sendEmail.length; i++) {
  var row = sendEmail[i];
  var Name = row[1]
  var job = row[2]
  var model = row[4]
  var info = "Job number: " + job + "\n"
  var emailAddress = row[0];
  var isEmailSent = row[14]
  if (isEmailSent != emailSent && no) {
  var message = "Dear " +   Name + "\n" + "
  var body = info + "\n" + message   
  var subject = "email";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body);
    sheet.getRange(startRow, 14, numRows, 1).setValue(emailSent);

 } }}}}
```

I have dedicated column M for the edit trigger. But, every time I enter a yes or a no in the first row, it sends the emails for all the other rows. If I put no on the first row, and yes on the send, it changed from not sending to sending all emails whereas if I put yes on the first row and no on the second, it flips between sending and not sending all emails.

I want to make the script look at column M and decide on a row by row basis on whether to send or not to send an email. This is the part I'm having trouble with and I've exhausted my search options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything you had in there works then this might be close.

```
function findTextsendupdate(e){
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=="My Email Sheet" && e.range.columnStart==13 && e.value=="TRUE") {
    const row=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var Name = row[1];
    var job = row[2];
    var model = row[4];
    var info = "Job number: " + job + "\n";
    var emailAddress = row[0];
    var isEmailSent = row[14];
    if (isEmailSent != "EmailSent" && MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()>0) {
      var message = "Dear " +   Name + "\n";
      var body = info + "\n" + message;   
      var subject = "email";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, body);
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,14).setValue('EmailSent');    
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using your script but it isn't sending emails when I type in TRUE in column M from row 3 onwards. I updated the "My Email Sheet" to my actual sheet name.

Comment: Oh I thought you were going to use a checkbox